# Extend model in plugin with "has_many" using a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a some code in an engine style plugin which includes some models. In my app I want to extend one of these models. I have managed to add both instance and class methods to the model in question by including a module from within an initializer.

However I cannot seem to add associations, callbacks etc. I get a 'method not found' error.

/libs/qwerty/core.rb

```
module Qwerty
  module Core
    module Extensions

      module User
        # Instance Methods Go Here 

        # Class Methods
        module ClassMethods
          has_many  :hits, :uniq => true # no method found

          before_validation_on_create :generate_code # no method found

          def something # works!
            "something"
          end
        end

        def self.included(base)
          base.extend(ClassMethods)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

/initializers/qwerty.rb

```
require 'qwerty/core/user'

User.send :include, Qwerty::Core::Extensions::User
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should work

```
module Qwerty
  module Core
    module Extensions
      module User
      # Instance Methods Go Here 

        # Class Methods
        module ClassMethods
          def relate
            has_many  :hits, :uniq => true # no method found

            before_validation_on_create :generate_code # no method found
          end

          def something # works!
            "something"
          end
        end

        def self.included(base)
          base.extend(ClassMethods).relate
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The old code is wrong cause the validation and the association are called upon module loading, and this module knows nothing about ActiveRecord. That's a general aspect of Ruby, code inside class or module bodies is called directly when loaded. You don't want that. To get around that you can use the above solution.

Comment: Gotcha:  When doing a 'reload!' in the console the class gets reloaded but because the module (in my case) is called from an initializer the module is not reapplied.

Comment: Further more at the moment it appears the code in the module only gets included when using the console, when the same code is called from a controller it fails. I'd like to post a code example but an answer does not seem right (this is not a forum after all)...

Comment: CONTROLLER: render :text => User.new.respond_to?('hits') and return #=> false
CONSOLE: User.new.respond_to?('hits') # => true
PREEMPT: I have rebooted the server :)

Comment: Must be code reloading - I set up a fresh Rails app, the first request (after server boot) works, the class in question has the module code included, the second request fails.

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to do this. A little more concise IMHO.

```
module Qwerty::Core::Extensions::User
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      has_many  :hits, :uniq => true
      before_validation_on_create :generate_code
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 3, this sounds like a good use case for ActiveSupport::Concern:

```
module Qwerty::Core::Extensions::User

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many  :hits, :uniq => true
    before_validation_on_create :generate_code 
  end
end

class User
  include Querty::Core::Extensions::User
  # ...
end
```

Here are the [ActiveSupport::Concern docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) and the most helpful [blog article](http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/09/20/concerning-yourself-with-active-support-concern/) on it I've found.