# How do I extend a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to extend a model in a Rails 2.3.11 app without touching the original source file. I need to add a `:has_many association` in it. I've tried the approach mentioned in [Extend model in plugin with "has_many" using a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519413/extend-model-in-plugin-with-has-many-using-a-module) without success. The class I need to extend is called `UbiquoUser`. Here the code I have in `lib/extensions.rb`:

```
module Sindicada
  module Extensions
    autoload :UbiquoUser, 'extensions/ubiquo_user'
  end
end
UbiquoUser.send(:extend, Sindicada::Extensions::UbiquoUser)
```

Here's what I have in `lib/extensions/ubiquo_user.rb`:

```
module Sindicada
  module Extensions
    module UbiquoUser
      module ClassMethods

        def has_audio_favorites
          has_many :audios, :through => :audios_favorite
        end

      end #ClassMethods

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods).has_audio_favorites
    end

    end #UbiquoUser
  end #Extensions
end #Sindicada
```

However, when I try to access the property audios of `UbiquoUser` on the app I get the error `undefined method audios for class blablabla`.

I also have the `require 'extensions'` in the `environment.rb` file and have checked that the files are being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have now is that you are extending your class, not including a module into it, so the `Sicada::Extensions::UbiquoUser#included` method never gets called.

To fix this, change this line:

```
UbiquoUser.send(:extend, Sindicada::Extensions::UbiquoUser)
```

to

```
UbiquoUser.send(:include, Sindicada::Extensions::UbiquoUser)
```